# WCN (connect to device using WPS) does not work under Windows 10

Tags: windows, delphi, wifi, wifi-protected-setup

I have implemented Delphi code to connect to a device using WCN (WPS) that works on Windows 7 & Windows 8(.1).

First, the code tries to detect the proper `IWCNDevice`, and once the proper device has been found it will:

- Set the password to empty using `wcnDevice.SetPassword( )`
- Create an object that implements IWCNConnectNotify. (= wcnConnectionNotify )
- Call `wcnDevice.Connect( wcnConnectionNotify )`

Under Windows 10, the wcnDevice is retrieved, the wcnConnectNotify object can be created and the following sequence of MSM / ACM Events is received:

> - source=0x10: 0x0010:MSM / Code=0x1: wlan_notification_msm_associating
> - source=0x10: 0x0010:MSM / Code=0x39:
> - source=0x10: 0x0010:MSM / Code=0x39:
> - ...
> - source=0x10: 0x0010:MSM / Code=0x2: wlan_notification_msm_associated
> - source=0x10: 0x0010:MSM / Code=0x3: wlan_notification_msm_authenticating
> - source=0x4: 0x0004:OneX / Code=0x1: OneXNotificationTypeResultUpdate
> - *10 times:*  source=0x10: 0x0010:MSM / Code=0x39:

Then `IWCNConnectNotify.ConnectFailed( )` fires with error code 0x80004005, without the WPS button being pressed on the device (and way too early for a timeout).

> - source=0x8: 0x0008:ACM / Code=0x14: wlan_notification_acm_disconnecting
> - ProcessAcmMessage: code=0x14 ssid= profile= reasonCode=0x0
> - source=0x8: 0x0008:ACM / Code=0xA: wlan_notification_acm_connection_complete
> - ProcessAcmMessage: code=0xA ssid=WCN Temporary Profile profile=WCN Temporary Profile reasonCode=0x38001

I have found no new information on the MSDN documentation for WCN that would indicate that something changed for Windows 10:
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Has anyone encountered the same issue, and was able to find a workaround?