# WCN(Windows Connect Now) framework does not work under Win10

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I am trying to use Windows WCN framework to achive the WPS(Wireless Protected Setup) functions in Windows 10. However, I meet some troubles. And I found someone meet the similar question, here is [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283181/wcn-connect-to-device-using-wps-does-not-work-under-windows-10)

In my program, I successfully detected the infos of the Access Point. Then I need to try to communicate with it by WSC 2.0 protocol. I do it by the following steps:
1、Create an object that implements IWCNConnectNotify, I call it WCNConnectNotify.
2、call `IWCNDevice::SetNetworkProfile()` function to set the profile files;
3、call `IWCNDevice::SetPassword()` function to set the mode of WPS;
4、call `IWCNDevice::Connect()` function to try to communicate with the AP by WSC 2.0 protocol.

However, on the one hand, when I try to use PIN_STA mode( enter the PIN code of AP into the network adapter) to connect with the AP, the `IWCNDevice::SetPassword()` function return `E_INVALIDARG`, which means that the arguments passed to this function are wrong! But The sample program can run on Win7, 
Win8 and Win8.1 successfully.  What's more, I print the arguments out in a file and found nothing wrong. The sample code like this:

```
//pDevice is a pointer of IWCNDevice class, pWcnConnectNotify is a pointer of WcnConnectNotify class.
WCN_PASSWORD_TYPE cfgType = WCN_PASSWORD_TYPE_PIN;
DWORD dwPinLen = 8;
UCHAR ucPin[8];
CopyMemory(ucPin, "12345670", 8);

hr = pDevice->SetPassword(cfgType, dwPinLen, ucPin);

if (hr != S_OK)
{
    printf("{%s} SetPassword() Failed! hr = 0x%x\n", __FUNCTION__, hr);
    continue;
}
    printf("{%s} SetPassword function success, now begin Connect Function.\n", __FUNCTION__);

hr = pDevice->Connect(pWcnConnectNotify);
```

On the other hand, When I try to use PBC mode, the `IWCNDevice::SetPassword()` function return `S_OK` successfully( Of course the arguments passed to it is different with the PIN_STA mode), and it can run the `IWCNDevice::Connect()` function, but it cannot communicate with the AP 
within the presupposed time(I set 10 seconds).

The most confused thing is that the same code can run successfully on Win7, Win8, and Win8.1, but without the Win10. I try to find the sample code of WindowsConnectNow in Win10 but get nothings. If I miss something important?
If anyone can do me a favor? I am truly appreciative if anyone can give me a useful suggestion！Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem. In our case we got crash (32bit app on 64bit OS) or error `RPC_X_BAD_STUB_DATA` (64bit app on 64bit OS) when calling `IWcnDevice::GetIntegerAttribute`. We found out that our problem was caused by broken SDK header file `WcnDevice.h`. The file was changed between SDK 8.1 and SDK 10. A new virtual method `SetNFCPasswordParams` was inserted between `SetPassword` and `Connect` methods of `IWcnDevice` interface. This highly likely leads to incorrect COM method dispatch when using mismatched SDK headers and `wcnapi.dll` (which implements `IWcnDevice`). A different virtual method is called instead of intended one.

In our case the problem was fixed when we used `WcnDevice.h` from SDK 8.1. Give it a try too.